# MediaWiki: how to prevent template from inserting white space?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

Today, I tried to create a template on Portuguese Wikipedia [inside one of my subpages](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usu%C3%A1rio:MisterSanderson/Predefini%C3%A7%C3%A3o:Item-artigo). It works fine with this code:

```
<includeonly>'''{{{num}}}''': <span style="font-family:monospace;">{{{date}}}</span> — [[{{{title}}}]]<!--
--> {{#if:{{{faults|}}}<!--
-->|({{{faults}}})<!--
--->|}}<br /></includeonly>
```

This code creates items like this:

> **81:** `28/feb` — [Der heimliche Aufmarsch gegen die Sowjetunion](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_heimliche_Aufmarsch_gegen_die_Sowjetunion) (one source)

But, I want to do more! The purpose of creating this template isn't just to set the date to monospace fonts... I want to add support for information about translations, and about deletions. Every time I tried to add text about deletions (you can check in the page history), the space between the lines got enormous, making [the "lists"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usu%C3%A1rio:MisterSanderson/Artigos_criados/Arquivo) very, very ugly...

For example, this is one of the solutions I tried to add deletion information:

```
<includeonly>'''{{{num}}}''': <span style="font-family:monospace;">{{{date}}}</span> — [[{{{title}}}]]<!--
--> {{#if:{{{faults|}}}<!--
-->|({{{faults}}})<!--
-->|}}<!--
-->{{#if:{{{Speedy-del|{{{Semi-speedy-del|{{{Consensus-del|}}}}}}}}}|
{{#if:{{{Speedy-del|}}}<!--
-->|<div style="margin-left:2em">✘ <small>Speedy deletion denied by {{{Speedy denier}}} on {{{Speedy date}}}</small></div><!--
-->|}}
{{#if:{{{Semi-speed-del|}}}<!--
-->|<div style="margin-left:2em">✘ <small>Semi-speedy deletion denied by {{{Semi-speedy denier}}} on {{{Semi-speedy date|}}}</small></div><!--
-->|}}
{{#if:{{{Consensus-del|}}}|<!--
--><div style="margin-left:2em">✘ <small>Consensus deletion denied on {{{Consensus date|}}}</small></div><!--
-->|}}
|<br />}}</includeonly>
```

Why is this happening to me? I could not find any typo. So the problem must be logical, and I gave up trying to find a solution alone. My logic must be broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML comments if you want to make sure there is no extra output from your template, but still need linebreaks etc for readability:

```
<includeonly><!--


  -->'''{{{num}}}''': {{{date}}}<!--


  -->[[{{{title}}}]]<!--


  -->{{#if:{{{faults|}}}| ({{{faults}}})|}}<br><!--


--></includeonly>
```

Comment: Okay, I will use the comments. But even without line breaks, the template inserts space between the lines, so the problem isn't that.

Comment: Do you have a lot of templates? In that case you can prevent linebreaks between them by ending the templates with a `<nowiki/>`. Or is it just one? Are you sure you are not sending spaces into the template? Without seeing the code, I can only guess.

Comment: You can see [here](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usu%C3%A1rio:MisterSanderson/Artigos_criados/Arquivo/2014) an example of how I'm using the template for which I'm needing help.

Comment: I see, and what is not working, exactly? The template seem to be working just fine?

Comment: To be clear: Each template is wrapped in a p-tag, because you have linebreaks between them, and ends in another linebreak, because you have inserted a br tag in the template

Comment: It's working fine because I reverted all changes that doesn't works properly. In [the history page of the template](https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Usu%C3%A1rio:MisterSanderson/Predefini%C3%A7%C3%A3o:Item-artigo&action=history) you can see what I attempted.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you'll have to be a bit more specific. How does the code look, that doesn't work as intended? What did you expect, and what happened?

Comment: Ughhh... I added to the original post the code I tried, but with the HTML comments on the unnecessary line breaks, and with some pipelines I missed... Now the code is working correctly....